# manhattan to euclidean metric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, metric-spaces

One may define a graph on a square lattice by taking the nodes of the lattice as graph vertices and the bonds of the lattice as edges. Suppose for simplicity that the nodes have integer $(x,y)$ coordinates with unit spacing in both dimensions.

The Manhattan norm of the vector with ${\bf v}=(x,y)$ is $|| {\bf v }||_m:=|x|+|y|$ and the Euclidean norm is $|| {\bf v }||_e:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Obviously, the Manhattan norm is the number of steps one has to take on the graph to join both ends of ${\bf v}$  by the shortest path. In the meantime the euclidean norm is the distance between both ends in the plane where the graph is embedded.

There is no one-to-one relationship between both norms. But there seems to be one between  $(|| {\bf v }||_m, N_{\bf v})$ and $||{\bf v}||_e$, where $N_{\bf v}$ is the number of shortest paths on the graph to join both ends of ${\bf v}$. This is at least what my computations on finite graphs show.

Now, my two questions.

- is there a proof for this ?
- does it hold with other lattices-graphs?

Comment: What is a "one to one relationship between norms"?

Comment: I mean when you know the Manhattan norm you can't deduce the Euclidean one.

Comment: So you want a proof that for fixed $A$ and $B$, all vectors $x$ with $||x||_m=A$ and $N_v(x)=B$ have the same euclidean norm?

Comment: That's it ! And vice versa

Comment: "And vice versa": That's not true, at least. $(3,4)$ and $(5,0)$ have the same Euclidean norm, for example.

Comment: As Rahul's post shows it, it is  a real $3D$ problem. You need 2 informations to infer the 3rd. E.g. if you know that $||{\bf v}||_e = 5$, you can't find $||{\bf v}||_m$ unless you know $N_{\bf v}$.

Comment: ... here $N_{(3,4)} = 35$ and $||(3,4)||_m=7$ while $N_{(5,0)} = 1$ and $||(5,0)||_e = 5$.

Comment: Anyway, what matters to me is really the proof that if you have $N_{\bf v}$ and $||{\bf v}||_m$, you can infer inambiguously $||{\bf v}||_e.$

Comment: And actually, the explicit functional form of $||{\bf v}||_e = f(||{\bf v}||_m, N_{\bf v})$ is the ultimate quest for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is, given the manhattan norm of a grid point, and the number of shortest grid-paths connecting the origin to that grid point, can we deduce the Euclidean norm of the grid point?

Let's work out what the number of shortest grid-paths is. Let $v=(x, y)$ be a grid-point, that is, $x,y\in \mathbb Z$. A simple combinatorial argument shows there are ${{|x|+|y|}\choose{|x|}}={{|x|+|y|}\choose{|y|}}$ possible paths from the origin to $v$ (any such path consists of $|x|+|y|$ "steps", and the only choice made for each step is whether it's horizontal or vertical).

So the question is, do the equations:

$$|x|+|y|=A$$
$${{|x|+|y|}\choose{|x|}}=B$$

determine $|x|$ and $|y|$, or at least $|x|^2+|y|^2$? Well, we have ${{A}\choose{|x|}}=B$, which, due to the symmetry of Pascal's triangle, narrows down the possibilities for $|x|$ to at most two possible values: if $a$ is one such value, $A-a$ is the other. By the first equation, the values for $|y|$ are then $A-a$ and $a$ respectively, so these two solutions are just swapping the values of $|x|$ and $|y|$. Since $|x|^2+|y|^2$ is symmetric, it will take on the same value for both solutions, so the above two equations do indeed determine the Euclidean norm of $v$.

I'm not sure exactly what generalization you're implying in your second question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The generalization I have in mind is to have the same kind of consideration with graphs derived from other lattices, especially triangular.